# Crash when opening Android window after using Unity ScrollRect component

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crashlytics-android, scrollrect

java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

Version '2020.3.14f1 (d0d1bb862f9d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/ANA-AN00/HWANA:10/HUAWEIANA-AN00/102.0.0.236C00:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
Timestamp: 2022-05-17 17:02:37+0800
pid: 11322, tid: 13025, name: UnityMain  >>> com.hwen.egg <<<
uid: 10270
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
r0  b7d0d000  r1  00ffffe9  r2  00000001  r3  00ffffdc
r4  00000000  r5  00000000  r6  00000010  r7  00420000
r8  00400001  r9  ec6eb17c  r10 00400011  r11 00001d10
ip  bbb87420  sp  ba47a8e8  lr  bade8ca1  pc  bb497e32

```
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00953e32  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #01 pc 002a4c9d  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #02 pc 002a1307  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #03 pc 002a121d  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #04 pc 00399cc1  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #05 pc 000bbf4d  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #06 pc 001cb68f  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #07 pc 002f62cb  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #08 pc 002f6ae7  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #09 pc 0087ac77  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #10 pc 00877da3  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #11 pc 00874025  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #12 pc 00875d93  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #13 pc 00889a6b  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #14 pc 00889999  /data/app/com.hwen.egg-kLmp4gehHdP02YIKdyPSiw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
      #15 pc 000040d6  <anonymous:d197e000>
```

managed backtrace:

```
#00 (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.TextGenerator:Populate_Internal_Injected (UnityEngine.TextGenerator,string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color&,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,int,int,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,single,single,single,single,bool,bool,uint&)
      #01 UnityEngine.TextGenerator:Populate_Internal (string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,int,int,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,single,single,single,single,bool,bool,uint&) <0x1a7>
      #02 UnityEngine.TextGenerator:Populate_Internal (string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,UnityEngine.VerticalWrapMode,UnityEngine.HorizontalWrapMode,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,UnityEngine.Vector2,UnityEngine.Vector2,bool,bool,UnityEngine.TextGenerationError&) <0x207>
      #03 UnityEngine.TextGenerator:PopulateAlways (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings) <0x2d7>
      #04 UnityEngine.TextGenerator:PopulateWithError (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings) <0x20b>
      #05 UnityEngine.TextGenerator:PopulateWithErrors (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings,UnityEngine.GameObject) <0x10b>
      #06 UnityEngine.UI.Text:OnPopulateMesh (UnityEngine.UI.VertexHelper) <0x1c3>
      #07 UnityEngine.UI.Graphic:DoMeshGeneration () <0x127>
      #08 UnityEngine.UI.Graphic:UpdateGeometry () <0x2b>
      #09 UnityEngine.UI.Text:UpdateGeometry () <0x37>
      #10 UnityEngine.UI.Graphic:Rebuild (UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdate) <0x6b>
      #11 UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdateRegistry:PerformUpdate () <0x3fb>
      #12 (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void ()
      #13 UnityEngine.Canvas:SendWillRenderCanvases () <0x33>
      #14 UnityEngine.Canvas:ForceUpdateCanvases () <0xb>
      #15 UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect:EnsureLayoutHasRebuilt () <0x2b>
      #16 UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect:LateUpdate () <0x83>
      #17 (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

    at libunity.0x953e32(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2a4c9d(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2a1307(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2a121d(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x399cc1(Native Method)
    at libunity.0xbbf4d(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1cb68f(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2f62cb(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2f6ae7(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x87ac77(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x877da3(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x874025(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x875d93(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x889a6b(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x889999(Native Method)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.Populate_Internal_Injected (UnityEngine.TextGenerator,string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color&,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,int,int,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,single,single,single,single,bool,bool,uint&)(Native Method)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.Populate_Internal (string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,int,int,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,single,single,single,single,bool,bool,uint&)(0x1a7:423)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.Populate_Internal (string,UnityEngine.Font,UnityEngine.Color,int,single,single,UnityEngine.FontStyle,bool,bool,int,int,UnityEngine.VerticalWrapMode,UnityEngine.HorizontalWrapMode,bool,UnityEngine.TextAnchor,UnityEngine.Vector2,UnityEngine.Vector2,bool,bool,UnityEngine.TextGenerationError&)(0x207:519)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.PopulateAlways (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings)(0x2d7:727)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.PopulateWithError (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings)(0x20b:523)
    at UnityEngine.TextGenerator.PopulateWithErrors (string,UnityEngine.TextGenerationSettings,UnityEngine.GameObject)(0x10b:267)
    at UnityEngine.UI.Text.OnPopulateMesh (UnityEngine.UI.VertexHelper)(0x1c3:451)
    at UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.DoMeshGeneration ()(0x127:295)
    at UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.UpdateGeometry ()(0x2b:43)
    at UnityEngine.UI.Text.UpdateGeometry ()(0x37:55)
    at UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.Rebuild (UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdate)(0x6b:107)
    at UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdateRegistry.PerformUpdate ()(0x3fb:1019)
    at <Module>.invoke_void ()(Native Method)
    at UnityEngine.Canvas.SendWillRenderCanvases ()(0x33:51)
    at UnityEngine.Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ()(0xb:11)
    at UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect.EnsureLayoutHasRebuilt ()(0x2b:43)
    at UnityEngine.UI.ScrollRect.LateUpdate ()(0x83:131)
```

Comment: Unity Version is 2020.3.14f1

Comment: You have a null reference somewhere. You'll need to include the relevant code as well if we are going to have any chance of helping.

Answer (score 1):

It is Unity bug.Upgrade my Unity 2020.3.14->2020.3.34 can fixed!